# trying to deploy an aspx page to webserver 'This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!'

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web

I have precompiled my code and added it to my webserver but when I try to access the page
I am getting this message

This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!

How do I remove this so I can see my page?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have deplyed a precompiled asp.net application. Did you remember to copy the generated assemlies (bin directory)?

Precompiled websites uses empty aspx files for routing hooks (unlike the mvc routeing engine). This is why you have a bunch of "empty" aspx files.